# Python: write an INI file for Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I would like to generate a simple .INI file using python with a precise structure, i.e.

```
[win_clones]
cl1 ansible_host=172.17.0.200
cl3 ansible_host=172.17.0.202
```

So far this is what I was able to produce:

```
[win_clones]
ansible_host = 172.17.0.200

[win_clones]
ansible_host = 172.17.0.202
```

I would like to:

- have only one [win_clones]
- include the name cl1/cl3
- remove the spaces, i.e. ansible_host=172.17.0.200

Below my data (a nested dictionary) and the script I am using:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
topush = { 'cl1': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.200']},
 'cl3': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.202']} }


def gen_host(data, group):
    ''' Takes a dictionary. It creates a INI file'''
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.add_section(group)
    with open('host_test', 'w') as outfile:
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            config.set(group,'ansible_host',''.join(value['ansible_host']))
            config.write(outfile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_host(topush, 'win_clones')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an "INI-*like*" file, not an INI file. You'll have to write it manually:

```
topush = {
    'cl1': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.200']},
    'cl3': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.202']}
}


def gen_host(data, group):
    ''' Takes a dictionary. It creates a INI file'''

    with open('host_test', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("[{}]\n".format(group))

        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            outfile.write("{} ansible_host={}\n".format(key, value['ansible_host']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_host(topush, 'win_clones')
```

Comment: You can also use f strings (Python 3):
`
with open('host_test', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(f'[{group}\n])
for key, value in data.items():
    outfile.write('{key} ansible_host={value["ansible_host"]}\n')
`

Answer (score 1):

Need to slightly correct function gen_host:

```
def gen_host(data, group):
    ''' Takes a dictionary. It creates a INI file'''
    config = ConfigParser()
    config.add_section(group)
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        config.set(group,'{0:s} ansible_host'.format(key),''.join(value['ansible_host']))

    with open('host_test', 'w') as outfile: config.write(outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the accepted answer but adapted to Python 3 (can't request an edit):

```
topush = {
    'cl1': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.200']},
    'cl3': {'ansible_host': ['172.17.0.202']}
}


def gen_host(data, group):
    ''' Takes a dictionary. It creates a INI file'''

    with open('host_test', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(f"[{group}]\n")

    for key, value in data.items():
        outfile.write(f"{key} ansible_host={value['ansible_host']}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_host(topush, 'win_clones')
```